# C++ read accented characters via ifsteam or cin

Tags: c++, character-encoding, iostream

So I'm a starter in C++, and I wanted to somehow get in text with accented characters.
I've read documentations, other questions, but none of them worked for me.
And I don't really understand it. Here is the file, and the output.

Text file:

```
abc
def
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
```

Console output:

```
abc
def
ĂˇrvĂ­ztĹ+rĹ' tĂĽkĂ¶rfĂşrĂłgĂcp
```

Somebody please help me, how can I **get the same text on the console, as in the file**?
And could somebody explain to me, **whats going on** here? ( i.e. **what are SetLocale()** and **.imbue()** )
Thank you for help!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); 

    std::string txt;
    std::ifstream fstream;

    fstream.open("C:\\Dev\\alma.txt");
    fstream.imbue(std::locale(""));
    
    while (getline(fstream, txt)) 
    {
        std::cout << txt << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    fstream.close();
    
}
```

Comment: have you tried  with `wstring/wifstream/wcout`?

Comment: Also, what's your environment, is it Windows?

Comment: What encoding is the file? What encoding is your terminal using?

Comment: Yes, Windows. For `wcout`, I need a `wstring`, right? How to use `getline()` with wstrings?

Comment: Where can I see terminal encoding?

Comment: @Vulkan07, it's the same, getline has an overload that takes wstring and wifstream, you have to make sure both arguments are w...

Comment: Oh, I didn't think that there's wifstream.
I've tried to write in the file with the program itself, then read it. It works. It turns out, I was an idiot, didn't check that Notepad++'s encoding was the incompatible part. I can't find any good encoding in Notepad++. It doesn't even need any wides, and the imbue functions.   Sorry guys :(. Anyway, still some experience with strings.

Comment: I forgot: what about `std::cin`? I tried it with wides and that didn't work...